# ¿Como cargar correctamente un archivo Javascript en un proyecto MVC .NET 5?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc, cshtml, .net-5

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto MVC .NET 5 en el cual tengo un script incluido en el MasterPage (_Layout) que realiza una validación de login. Y dentro de esta MasterPage tengo un menú donde pongo el acceso a los diversos módulos que tiene mi aplicación (modulo1 & modulo2).

Si utilizo la sintaxis de razor para abrir una vista (asp-action & asp-controller) que se "renderiza" en la section de @RenderBody funciona "bien" a excepción de que por cada vez que abro una vista me RECARGA toda la página haciendo esto que tambien se vuelva a cargar y ejecutar mi script que tengo en el MasterPage y fallen algunas cosas, es decir, por cada vez que abro un módulo se realiza la validación de las credenciales del usuario (login) cuando lo que busco es que se carga una única vez.

Código Razor:

```
<a class="view" id="Checklist" asp-action="Checklist" asp-controller="Menu"><span>Checklist Equipos</span></a>
<a class="view" id="Reportes" asp-action="Reportes" asp-controller="Menu"><span>Reportes</span></a>
```

Ante esto, estuve investigando un poco y encontré que para "solucionar" el inconveniente de que se este recargando por cada vez que se abre un módulo (view), se puede utilizar AJAX. Lo implemente y si "funciono" pero también encontré que al "no" refrescar la página si entro por primera vez al modulo1 y luego vuelvo a hacer click al modulo1, se vuelve a cargar la página y su respectivo JS ya que lo cargo al final de cada HTML y al suceder esto, marca errores de que ya esta "cargado" un JS con toda la misma funcionalidad, es decir, si tenia un var numero = 1; cuando se vuelva a cargar, no se "elimina" y carga, si no que, solamente lo duplica y marca errores.

La duda es. ¿Cómo puedo cargar de manera correcta los archivos JS para cada vista que se abre de manera independiente sin que el script del master page se este recargando ó abrir las vistas sin necesidad de refrescar la página entera? ya que previamente había realizado lo siguiente para abrirlo con AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Menu/" + cNombreVista,
    success: function (datos) {
        $("#contenido-derecho").html(datos);
    }
})
```

Comment: Y por qué no cargas el script desde la vista con `@Script{}`? Cada vista puede cargar su propio set de scripts.

Comment: ¿Tendrás algún ejemplo de cómo realizarlo? Ando a ciegas, e intentado mil maneras y no logro dar con la respuesta, se sigue ciclando el fichero JS. @Arriel